# Including time tags on (X,Y,Z) coordinate plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a dataframe flight data with X, Y, and Z location coordinates as well as time. I would like to create a 3-D plot where I can either:

1) Hover over each scatter point and have it display the X, Y, Z and Time at that point

OR

2) Add annotations to specific points. For instance, adding annotations for all points where Time > 900 and X < 500.

I am also open to any other methods that could give similar visualizations. As of now, I use a colorbar to show the increase of time during the trajectory, but I need to give a more detailed visualization.

EDIT: To be clear, the main problem I am trying to solve is how to annotate each data point with all of the information in each row of the dataframe (i.e. X,Y,Z, and Time).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"X": np.linspace(0,500,1001), 
                     "Y": np.linspace(100,1000,1001), 
                     "Z": np.linspace(0,100,1001),
                     "Time": np.linspace(0,1000,1001)})

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = "3d")
img = ax.scatter(data.X, data.Y, data.Z, c = data.Time, cmap = "Greens")
fig.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the hover data, you could do it with `plotly`. As of recent versions, you can use `plotly.express`, which is bundled into `plotly`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

data = pd.DataFrame({"X": np.linspace(0,500,1001),
                     "Y": np.linspace(100,1000,1001),
                     "Z": np.linspace(0,100,1001),
                     "Time": np.linspace(0,1000,1001)})

fig = px.scatter_3d(data, x = "X", y = "Y", z = "Z", hover_data = ["Time"])

# your plot will be rendered in your browser
fig.show()
```

If you're using an older version of `plotly`, or you don't want to use the `express` syntax, you can achieve the same with:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({"X": np.linspace(0,500,1001),
                     "Y": np.linspace(100,1000,1001),
                     "Z": np.linspace(0,100,1001),
                     "Time": np.linspace(0,1000,1001)})

fig = go.Figure(
    data = [
        go.Scatter3d(
            x = data["X"], 
            y = data["Y"], 
            z = data["Z"], 
            mode = "markers"
        ),
        hover_data = ["Time"]
    ]
)


fig.show()
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'm looking for, except I need a way to include the time with each coordinate. I feel like that is the crux of my problem. Is that possible to include if it's not one of the three axes in the plot?

Comment: Oops, missed that part of the question, see edits :)